# using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString to extract the src of an img then assigning the url to a NSString OR NSURL

Tags: javascript, cocoa, webview, image, src

I'm using a WebView in my cocoa application, I would like to extract an image's url from the WebView.

I've been trying to use stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString to extract it with no avail.

```
NSString *imageURLString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$('#id1.class1.img').attr('src');"];
```

#id1 and .class1 are just place holders, the structure of the html looks like this

```
<ol id="id1">
   <div class="class1">
      <img src="url.jpg">
```

I would like to get the url as string and then turn it into NSURL to use with NSData, however, if I can get NSURL straight from the javascript, that's even better.

Comment: Does the page in question have jQuery loaded? The JavaScript syntax you are using is specific to jQuery.

Comment: @Rob Yes, I am using jQuery in other places and it works fine.

Comment: OK! I figured out the right JavaScript for this, it should be `$('#id1').find('.class1').find('img').attr("src");`

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd make this an actual answer since no one else left any. The right JavaScript for this is

```
$('#id1').find('.class1').find('img').attr("src");
```